# EF7 nested Include not showing in Razor .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, entity-framework-core

I have my models like this:

1. Goup.cs
2. GroupUser (pivot table)
3. ApplicationUser (User) -> 4. Profile

And now I want to show the data in Profile on a details page when the User belongs to the group. I'm doing this like this:

```
private IEnumerable<GroupUser> GetUsers(int groupId)
    {
        IEnumerable<GroupUser> model = null;

        if(groupId == 0)
        {
            model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.OrderByDescending(o => o.GroupId).AsEnumerable();
        }
        else
        {
            model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId).Include(p => p.User.Profile).OrderByDescending(o => o.GroupId).AsEnumerable();
        }

        return model;
    }
```

This works, if I just want to display the UserId, ... (so the data in the Pivot table) with this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.GroupUser>
@if(Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{   
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
@user.UserId</h2>
}
}
```

But for some reason I can't display the data in the Included tables? 
Normally you would do something like this: @user.User.Profile.XXXX but then I get the error: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
So this would mean the return is null, but there are users in the pivot table with a profile.

The models:

Group.cs:

```
namespace App.Models
{
public class Group : Item
{
    public Group() : base()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public Int16 Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }

    /* Foreign Keys */
    public Nullable<Int16> RegionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lets> Lets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> Users { get; set; }
}
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
namespace App.Models.Identity
{
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{   
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DeletedAt { get; set; } 

    /* Virtual or Navigation Properties */
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> Groups { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Lets> Lets { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }   
}
}
```

GroupUser:

```
namespace App.Models
{
public class GroupUser
{
    public GroupUser()
    {

    }

    public Nullable<Int16> GroupId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
}
```

Profile.cs:

```
namespace App.Models
{
public class Profile : Item
{
    public Profile() : base()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Int16 Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Int16 Credits { get; set; }
    public Int16 Postalcode { get; set; }
}
}
```

How can i display the nested data with razor?

Comment: will you share the model ? I think there is something wrong there.

Comment: I have updated the question :).

Comment: Use `ToList()` in stead of `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: private IEnumerable<GroupUser> GetUsers(int groupId)
        {
            IEnumerable<GroupUser> model = null;
            
            if(groupId == 0)
            {
                model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.Include(g =>     g.Group).OrderByDescending(o => o.GroupId).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId).Include(p => p.User.Profile).ToList();
            }
            
            return model;
        }

So I ended up with this. But this dit not work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId)
    .Include(gu => gu.User)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.Profile)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.GroupId)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Don't get freaked out when intellisense doesn't work for the `ThenInclude`, just type it, it will compile.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Intellisense did not freak out :)!. For future readers, Then I just got my data in razor like this:
`@model IEnumerable<App.Models.GroupUser>
@if(Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
{   
 @foreach(var user in Model)
 {
             @user.User.Profile.FirstName
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

try to include the user-reference

model = _kletsContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupId)**.Include(p => p.User)**.Include(p => p.User.Profile).OrderByDescending(o => o.GroupId).AsEnumerable();

Comment: This did not work either. I assume I already have the user linked too  (my intellisense says so) :).

Comment: add the annotation [ForeignKey("UserId")] before the line 
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } in Groupuser.