# Need to query related data with ONE query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

That is my simple ERD

[image]

For a given schoolyearId I want to load all schoolclasses + related pupils + related subjects.

```
  var schoolclasses = context.Schoolclasses
                .Include(s => s.Pupils)
                // How to get here the SubjectPupil + Subject for each pupil?
                .Where(s => s.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId);
```

The only special thing in this ERD is the Many to Many relation with Pupil and Subject.

In EF7 I created a bridge table for it like SubjectPupil.

How would you extend my query above or do it correctly to get the Subject data for each pupil in the above query?

Comment: Again... Why close this question? Any comment ?

Answer (score 1):

For all the downvoters and closer idiots without comment.

From this SO answer I found out that Intellisense did not show up for the .ThenInclude() correctly. Thus I thought the query does not work:

[EF7 nested Include not showing in Razor .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474237/ef7-nested-include-not-showing-in-razor-net/34476369#34476369)

The solution to get the data I wanted is this.

```
  var schoolclasses = await context.Schoolclasses
                .Include(x => x.Pupils)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.PupilsSubjects)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Subject)
                .Where(s => s.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId)
                .ToListAsync();
```

**Just type the name of your property to ThenInclude and build the project, it will compile!**

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the classes code, but if in essence your question is how you eager load related entiites from multiple levels, you can do something like this:

```
var schoolclasses = context.Schoolclasses
    .Include(s => s.Pupils.Select(pupil => pupil.SubjectPupil.Subject))
    .Where(s => s.SchoolyearId == schoolyearId);
```

[Here's the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj574232.aspx#eagerLevels) that describes this behaviour.

Comment: The class code is the setup I told in the diagram. There is only ONE way you can setup 1:N or N:M relatio in EF7. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes:-January-8,-2015 Your .Select is the way it was used in EF6 but EF7 with ThenInclude should replace that, but that does not work in my case somehow. Can you try that with ThenInclude please, maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: That way it compiles:                     .Include(s => s.Pupils.Select(pupil => pupil.PupilsSubjects.Select(c => c.Subject)))
 but I get a runtime Exception: SubQueryExpression can not be converted to a System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression

Comment: When I append a ThenInclude(x => x.PupilsSubjects) after the first Include intellisense gets me a list of linq methods but not my concrete types?